# UDP recvfrom thread use too much CPU resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, udp, winsockets

I am writing a Windows 7 visual c++ server application, which should receive UDP datagrams with 3.6 MB/s.
I have a main thread where the recvfrom() receives the data. The socket is a non-blocking socket and has 64kB receive buffer. If no data has been received on the socket the thread executes a sleep(1).

My problem is that the thread uses up almost 50% of my dual-core processor and I have no idea how could I decrease it. Wireshark use only 20% of it, so my main goal is to achieve a similar percentage.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you are feeling brave you could consider using Boost::async - but it is essentially @simonc answer about using select wrapped up in a class library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than polling you could use a select-like approach to wait for either data to arrive at your socket or the client to decide to shutdown:

First make your socket non-blocking:

```
u_long nonBlocking = 0;
WSAEventSelect(sock, NULL, 0);
ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nonBlocking);
```

then use [WSAWaitForMultipleEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms742219(v=vs.85).aspx) to wait until either data arrives or you want to cancel the recv:

```
int32_t MyRecv(THandle sock, WSAEVENT* recvCancelEvt,
               uint8_t* buffer, uint32_t bufferBytes)
{
    int32_t bytesReceived;
    WSAEVENT evt;
    DWORD ret;
    HANDLE handles[2];

    event = WSACreateEvent();
    if (NULL == evt) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (0 != WSAEventSelect(handle->iSocket, evt, FD_READ|FD_CLOSE)) {
        WSACloseEvent(evt);
        return -1;
    }

    bytesReceived = recv(sock, (char*)buffer, bufferBytes, 0);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR==received && WSAEWOULDBLOCK==WSAGetLastError()) {
        handles[0] = evt;
        handles[1] = *recvCancelEvt;
        ret = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(2, handles, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE);
        if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == ret) {
            bytesReceived = recv(handle->iSocket, (char*)buffer, bufferBytes, 0);
        }
    }
    WSACloseEvent(evt);
    return bytesReceived;
}
```

Client code would call `WSASetEvent` on `recvCancelEvt` if it wanted to cancel a recv.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your example is very instructive. Anyway, I had to realize that not my simple receiving mechanism was inefficient, rather the way as I processed the data.

Answer (score 1):

While solutions based on Select or blocking sockets are the correct approach, the reason you're running one core at 100% is due to the behaviour of Sleep:-

Look at the docs for [WinAPI sleep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> This function causes a thread to relinquish the remainder of its time
>   slice and become unrunnable for an interval based on the value of
>   dwMilliseconds. The system clock "ticks" at a constant rate. ***If
>   dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the
>   thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time.***

So, if you're polling, you either need to use a much larger sleep time (maybe 20Ms, which is typically a bit greater than the Windows tick rate), or use a more accurate multimedia timer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like most of the times your call to recvfrom does not return data. Sleeping 1 ms is not much. You should think about increasing the sleep time (cheap, but not best solution) or, the better solution, think about using an event driven approach. Use `select()` or Windows API to block until the socket is signalled or some other event you are interested in occurs and then call `recvfrom`. You might need to redesign your program's main loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a boost::asio::io_service. We receive about 200MB/s of UDP multicast traffic while maxing out a modern CPU. This includes a full reliability protocol and data dispatch to the application. The bottleneck in profiling is the processing, not the boost::asio receive. [Code here](https://github.com/Eyescale/Collage/blob/master/co/rspConnection.cpp)

Comment: I haven't tired boost libraries yet, but the main problem was the processing rather than the receiving.